# reason for difference in power.prop.test and epiR::epi.sscompb results

Tags: r, binary, sample-size

I was trying to rework the examples in Epidemiology Study Design and Data Analysis by Mark Woodward  using R.
Example 8.12 deals with calculation of sample size to test for a population proportion of 0.3 against the one sided alternative that it is greater than 0.32.

I tried two commands

```
power.prop.test(n = NULL, p1=0.3, p2=0.32, power =0.9, alternative = "one.sided")
epiR::epi.sscompb(n = NA, treat = 0.3, control = 0.32, power = 0.9, sided.test = 1 )
```

The results (sample size) given by the two functions are very different.

```
Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 9157.159
             p1 = 0.3
             p2 = 0.32
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9
    alternative = one.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

```
$n.total
[1] 4568
$n.treat
[1] 2284
$n.control
[1] 2284
$power
[1] 0.9
$lambda
[1] 0.937500 1.066667
```

The result by epi.sscompb agrees with the value in the book.

Can someone tell me if there is an error in the code? If there is no error in the code, why are the results different?

Thanks,
ajith

Comment: Hi Ajith! Welcome to StackOverflow! If the issue is with the statistics portion, then stats.stackexchange.com would be your best bet

Comment: I am not sure if it is statistics that I don't understand or if it is the R code that is the problem. Any way, now I have posted at Cross Validated too. Thanks.